# How To Close A VCL Metro App With Touch Swiping

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

If you create a new VCL Metro App by selecting File-New-VCL Metropolis App in the IDE, then run the app when you try to close the app with a finger drag from the top of the screen to the bottom of the screen the app appears to close, and the Start Page becomes visible but the app does not actually close.  If you swipe-in from the left edge of the start page, the metro app is still running.

I tried adding Application.Terminate in the OnFormHide event, but the app still does not close.  The only way to close the app is by swiping up from the bottom of the screen so that the app bar is visible, then touch the close button.

So my question is- How go you close a VCL Metro Application with touch swiping?

The same thing occurs if you create a FireMonkey Metro App.

Comment: Isn't that default behaviour? AFAIK that's completely normal with Metro.

Comment: No that is Not the default behavior.  All Microsoft Metro apps actually close that way.  Close is the default behavior.  You can test this by swiping from the left edge of the screen.  When you swipe, the next loaded app appears.  With Microsoft apps, after you close the app and then swipe the app is not present anymore, but with Delphi it is present.